# Google Analytics API: filter by URI start from substring

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My site has urls like this

```
www.domain.com/fr/profile/id/1234/...
www.domain.com/nl/profile/id/1234/...
www.domain.com/de/profile/id/1234/...
www.domain.com/profile/id/1234/...
```

fr, nl, de is the language of the visitor.
I want to know the amount of users visiting a profile page so i filter on pagepath like this, but it returns a value for each language...

```
ga:pagePath=@/profile/id/1234
```

How can i start filtering from this path and exclude everything that comes before this path so i get the users for all languages combined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is nothing wrong with filtering it like that.
I added pagepath as a dimension thinking it was necessary to filter on it, but that's not needed.
Just don't use pagepath as a dimension and it works fine.